# Color in lstlisting is black to different language

Tags: xetex, color, listings, greek

I am new to XeLaTeX and I want to display python code using listings package. The problem is that greek characters in comments or strings are colored black.

This is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek]{Linux Libertine O}
\newfontfamily\greekfontsf[Script=Greek]{Linux Libertine O}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{greek}
\usepackage[left=1.91cm,right=1.91cm,top=2.54cm,bottom=2.54cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{accsupp}
\DeclareRobustCommand\squelch[1]{\BeginAccSupp{method=plain,ActualText={}}#1\EndAccSupp{}}
\newcommand\emptyaccsupp[1]{\BeginAccSupp{ActualText={}}#1\EndAccSupp{}}


\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}


\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
    backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},   
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{magenta},
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
    stringstyle=\color{codepurple},
    basicstyle=\footnotesize,
    breakatwhitespace=false,         
    breaklines=true,                 
    captionpos=b,                    
    keepspaces=true,                 
    numbers=left,                    
    numbersep=5pt,                  
    showspaces=false,                
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,                  
    tabsize=2
}

\lstset{style=mystyle}


\begin{document}

Εδώ έχει ελληνικά some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 

\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python]
import numpy as np
    
def incmatrix(genl1,genl2):
    m = len(genl1)
    n = len(genl2)
    M = None #to become the incidence matrix
    VT = np.zeros((n*m,1), int)  #dummy variable
    
    #THERE IS A PROBLEM στα ελληνικα 3χ3
    print("ελληνικά και english")
    
    M1 = bitxormatrix(genl1)
    M2 = np.triu(bitxormatrix(genl2),1) 

    for i in range(m-1):
        for j in range(i+1, m):
            [r,c] = np.where(M2 == M1[i,j])
            for k in range(len(r)):
                VT[(i)*n + r[k]] = 1;
                VT[(i)*n + c[k]] = 1;
                VT[(j)*n + r[k]] = 1;
                VT[(j)*n + c[k]] = 1;
                
                if M is None:
                    M = np.copy(VT)
                else:
                    M = np.concatenate((M, VT), 1)
                
                VT = np.zeros((n*m,1), int)
    
    return M
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

And this is the output:
[image: output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that if you put on style this parameter `texcl=true` treats the comments as tex document. Also with the following code changes the characters from **utf8** to **ansii** cause some times it causes problems (in matlab at least) when copying and paste from pdf.

```
\lstset{literate=%
{*}{{*}}1
{-}{{-}}1
}
```

Also `columns=fullflexible` is good choice if you want to copy and paste from pdf.

```
\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
    backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},   
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{magenta},
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
    stringstyle=\color{codepurple},
    basicstyle=\footnotesize,
    breakatwhitespace=false,         
    breaklines=true,                 
    captionpos=b,                    
    keepspaces=true,                 
    numbers=left,                    
    numbersep=5pt,                  
    showspaces=false,                
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,                  
    tabsize=2,
    columns=fullflexible,
    texcl=true
}
```